# How to bind array to ag-grid column dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am working on ag-grid component. In this grid I have to bind only column in vertical format. suppose I have an array ["0.1", "0.4", "cn", "abc"] and I have to display it in ag-grid component as below and i don't have any rowData.

```
    0.1
---------------------------------
    0.4
---------------------------------
    cn
---------------------------------
    abc
--------------------------------
```

Is it possible to bind above array in vertical format using ag-grid.
or is there any other solution, Please any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

my html file:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: can u change the format of the array to  ["0.1"],[ "0.4"], ["cn"], ["abc"]

Comment: I am getting the same format as I have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
export class MyGridApplicationComponent {
    public gridOptions: GridOptions;
    public myArray =  ["0.1", "0.4", "cn", "abc"] ;

    constructor() {
        this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
          enableSorting: true,
          enableFilter: true
        };
        this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
            {
                headerName: "",
                field: "value",
                width: 100
            }
        ];
        this.gridOptions.rowData = 
        this.myArray.map(function(item) {
  return {"value":item};
})
}
}
```

and in html:

```
<div style="width: 100px;">
    <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="ag-theme-fresh" [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
    </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-ddqdgk)

Comment: It does not show the grid after adding ag-grid-community import tag for GridOptions.